# Importar XLS y crear tabla KNIME

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, excel, oracle, tablas

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy usando KNIME para importar un archivo XLS para luego crear una tabla en la Base de Datos ORACLE. Puedo realizarlo pero quiero continuar el FLUJO SECUENCIAL para seguir manipulando la tabla creada pero el NODO no me lo permite. Como podría corregir este problema?
Adjunto una captura de pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero seguir manipulando la tabla creada pero el NODO "DataBase Write" no me lo permite. ¿Cual es el NODO correcto que debería usar?